# centering a a fixed with div within a fixed width div

Tags: html, css, layout

Hello I am having trouble centering a div, with `margin:0 auto;` I have my HTML structured like this,

```
<div class="wrapper">  
    <div class="content">  
        <nav class="mini">  
            <!-- nav class mini content -->
        </nav>   
    </div>  
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this,

```
    .wrapper {  
        width:1154px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

.content {  
     width:906px;  
     margin:0 auto;  
     text-align:center;
}

.mini {
   width: 350px;  
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

I would expect `.mini` to be centered within `.content` but it is not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks good to me: http://jsfiddle.net/NEc3r/

Comment: @Samuel take a look at my fiddle and you will see my problem http://jsfiddle.net/pYbAP/

Comment: Looks fine to me too. Maybe you aren't looking at the right browser resolution.

Comment: @sico87 if you're talking about the red boxes the reason they aren't centered is because they are in .mini which is a fixed width (which is required for auto margin centering to work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your div are centered. The only problem is your li's are floated left. So make your ul center & it will look good.

`.mini ul {display:inline-block;}`

fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/pYbAP/7/

Comment: auto margin has no effect but it works because a parent element has text-align: center on it.

Answer (score 0):

On your fiddle your .mini div is centered within .content but you haven't centered the content you have within .mini

You'd need to apply the margin:0 auto css to the UL in there too and apply text-align:center to .mini

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your giving a `max-width` to the `.wrapper div`. When the browser's width is smaller than 1154px, the `.wrapper`s width becomes the browsers width. If you make the browser window small enough, the `.wrapper`s width becomes smaller than it's child `.content`´s width. If the parent is smaller than the child, then `margin: 0 auto`, can't do what it's there to do since `auto` becomes 0.

Try turning the `max-width` into `width`, and it will work like you want it to, at whichever browser width.

Answer (score 0):

Because nav is an html5 element, you have to display it as a block first: nav{ display: block; } In fact, any element that is not displayed as block by default cannot be centered by using the margin property. Most frameworks do that for you already but you could always use this css reset code from [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).